# multi-threaded increment and skip 0 without a lock?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, atomic

I have a ushort counter (that occasionally rolls over). The messaging protocol that uses this value disallows a 0. I need some thread-safe way to increment this counter (stored in a class field) every time I read it, which isn't hard if I store it as an int and use the Interlocked.Increment. However, I'm not sure how to incorporate skipping 0 into that. It's okay if I occasionally skip a few numbers; my output sequence doesn't have to be perfect. I cannot ever reuse the same number in any block of 4000. I would like to avoid using a lock.

Comment: can you just have a `do { result = Interlocked.Increment(ref value); } while (result==0);` to avoid the 0?

Comment: I think that would work as long as result was cast to a ushort in the while check. It seems that in the collision case it would only skip the 1.

Comment: @MarcGravell Some other threads could read the 0 value in-between the `Interlocked.Increment`s.

Comment: @xanatos so? that doesn't matter - because all the code after a new number would run this same accessor - so nobody will ever get  a zero

Comment: @MarcGravell You could have pure readers return 1 when they read 0 and "fake it"... (they don't know if it's already 1... but they know that it will become 1 in a few instants if it's 0)

Comment: @xanatos no, not fake it - keep reading until a non-zero - which effectively means "once more". Faking it risks duplicates with genuine 1s. look at the do / while - it can never return zero, and only duplicates at wrap around

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one:

Given:

```
static int value = ushort.MaxValue;
```

And in the code:

```
int temp, temp2;

do
{
    temp = value;
    temp2 = temp == ushort.MaxValue ? 1 : temp + 1;
}
while (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref value, temp2, temp) != temp);
```

You'll have to use an `int` and then cast it (for example in a `get` property), because the `Interlocked` aren't for all basic types.

We could probably make it a little faster in highly threaded contexts like this:

```
int temp = value;

while (true)
{
    int temp2 = temp == ushort.MaxValue ? 1 : temp + 1;

    int temp3 = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref value, temp2, temp);

    if (temp3 == temp)
    {
        break;
    }

    temp = temp3;
}
```

In this way we have to do one less read on failure.

As I've written in the comment, the central idea of this code is to increment in a temporary variable (`temp2`) the counter, and then trying to exchange the old value that we know with the new value (`Interlocked.CompareExchange`). If no one touched the old value in-between (`Interlocked.CompareExchange() == temp`) then we have finished. If someone else incremented the value then we do another try. The `ushort` is simulated by the use of an `int` with a fixed maximum value (`temp == ushort.MaxValue ? 1 : temp + 1`).

The second version, on failure of the `Interlocked.CompareExchange()` reuses the value read by the function as the new basis on which to add 1.

The `Interlocked.CompareExchange` used in that way can be used as a basis for building other `Interlocked` operations (you want an `Interlocked.Multiply`? You do a "standard" multiply and then try to `Interlocked.CompareExchange` the old value)

Comment: I still need a ushort result. I'm not sure that this detects the ushort rollover.

Comment: That looks kind of racey to me. I think this would break when called concurrently from a number of threads.

Comment: @spender Doable by using an `int` as a backing field. Modified the code.

Comment: @spender The first read (`temp = value;`) could be dirty, but if it's dirty the `Interlocked.CompareExchange` will fail and will force a "true" read of the value. Then the value is rereaded, but at this point we are "in sync" with the other threads. If two threads enter at the same time in the block of code, only one `Interlocked.CompareExchange` will be successful while the other will fail. The second version has one less read on failure (we reuse the `Interlocked.CompareExchange` read)

Comment: +1: This is absolutely the correct answer. For those that don't know, the top example is the basic template for creating interlocked-like variations of complex operations. I've done this on multiple occasions and works quite well. It is a tried-and-true pattern.